# "Infinite" Panel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

For an internal tool, I need to create something akin to Blender's node editor (see image below) or UE4's blueprint editor with WPF.

[image: Blender's node editor]

The backend and individual blocks aren't a problem, but I'm not sure how to go about an arbitrary sized and expanding canvas. I thought about using a `Canvas` inside a `ScrollViewer`, but I think that would be difficult to scroll left (i.e. if the user had to add nodes to the left of what the `ScrollViewer` thinks is the edge). I'm relatively new to WPF, so could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to write your own custom `Panel` implementation with `IScrollInfo` interface. Through this interface you can dynamically change extent size of your panel at any time using `ScrollOwner.InvalidateScrollInfo()` method. Here are some links that will get you started:

[Ben Constable excellent blog post series about IScrollInfo](http://web.archive.org/web/20150128050816/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/01/05/509991.aspx)

[Virtualizing Canvas example implementation](http://web.archive.org/web/20151116055422/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx)

Your final code should contain an `ItemsControl` that is using your custom panel inside a `ScrollViewer`. As for drawing the connections between blocks, I personally would use transparent layer above your panel with `OnRender` code that draws them using `DrawingContext`.

EDIT:

Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182683/NetworkView-A-WPF-custom-control-for-visualizing-a). There is a working node editor-like control here.